# Yeoman.io with nested prompts produces undefined error in Inquirer.js

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm creating my first (real) Yeoman.io generator, which has some nested prompts (i.e. The answer of one prompt influences the presentation of other prompts and actions).

I've traced through my code, and on the surface it looks like I'm "opening and closing" my prompts appropriately, but at the very end of the script it looks like there's still an open readline (from Inquirer.js), and an extra onCompletion fires after the readlines have been closed.

I'm going to assume that this isn't a problem with the libraries (either Yeoman.io or Inquirer.js), it's a problem with the way that I'm prompting, or there's a different way to do what I'm trying to do.

```
INQUIRER onCompletion
Prompted for initialize, user said true
User said to initialize, exec git init
INQUIRER onCompletion
INQUIRER ERROR: TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeListener' of null
GITHOOKS PROMPT:  undefined
GITHOOKS PROMPT:  undefined

/untethered/app/index.js:178
        cb();
        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at UntetheredGenerator.<anonymous> (/untethered/app/index.js:178:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/untethered/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js:88:7)
```

Code is here: https://github.com/pollensoft/untethered/blob/master/app/index.js

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've found my answer in one of the following links:
https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/278
https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js#question

Comment: Fixed here: https://github.com/pollensoft/untethered/commit/4f8e683c197c1365829ae66b375c59a2d730631b

SO won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours.  If I forget to come back, this may appear unanswered.  Way to go Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: You want to add the answer now ?

Comment: I don't seem to get any notifications from Stack Overflow, and I don't log in very often, I've posted the answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here: github.com/pollensoft/untethered/commit/… SO won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours. If I forget to come back, this may appear unanswered. Way to go Stack Overflow! :)